# Android, SWIG and bidirectional communication

Tags: c++, android, android-ndk, swig

I have a C++ api I can't change which:

- exposes object (easy)
- exposes interfaces that have to be derived by caller (classical trigger-listener design pattern).

I managed to wrap this API to python using SWIG and the director feature, which allows cross-language derivation.
However, when I tried to compile it using ndk, to expose it in Dalvik's VM in Android, I discovered that directors in SWIG are supported through RTTI, and that Android does not support RTTI.

Any idea on how I could workaround this limitation? Basically, I have an easy way of exposing my native objects in Java using JNI and SWIG, but I need to be able to trigger my Java code from native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does support RTTI and exceptions from NDK r5. Just add `-fexceptions` and `-frtti` compilation flags and also add line `APP_STL := gnustl_static` to the `Application.mk` file.

Comment: and does the dalvik VM suport loading jni compiled with these options?

Answer (score -1):

you'll need to write your own JNI that doesn't use RTTI, i'm afraid.

Comment: Side question : is there a way for swig/any other wrapper tool to write this for me ?